# How to build python3.7 on linux build for windows10 host

Tags: python-3.x, mingw-w64

I'm looking for a modern recipe for building a 64-bit python 3.7 on ubuntu linux for a host windows10 machine.  I have attempted using the linux host version of mingw-64, but it seems the python configure script does not support this flavor of cross build. Is there a work around?